# Object indentation in emacs php-mode

Tags: php, zend-framework, emacs, php-mode

I would like to have this indentation like Zend does on objects:

```
$this->getResponse()
     ->appendBody('Hello World');
```

But what I have now is:

```
$this->getResponse()
  ->appendBody('Hello World');
```

and I don't have any idea how I can do in this way.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

php-mode is a fairly primitive mode that doesn't quite get the semantics of PHP. It's based on cc-mode so you can tweak its indentation settings by tweaking cc-mode's settings. There is an overview of the settings [here](http://php-mode.sourceforge.net/html-manual/Indentation.html), but cc-mode has a lot more that you can play with. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168621/php-mode-for-emacs) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Recent releases of php-mode (available via MELPA) can do what you want; simply set `php-lineup-cascaded-calls` to `t` in your emacs configuration.

```
(setq php-lineup-cascaded-calls t)
```

Or use the customization interface `M-x customize-group RET php RET`.